# Adding event listeners without overriding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, keyup

I am setting an `eventListener` for `keyup` on a certain input.  Then later in the code, I need to be able to add another event to that listener without overriding the first one (both functions must execute).  Is this possible to accomplish?

I've tried:

```
$input.keyup(function...)

$input.bind('keyup',function(){...});

$input.addEventListener('keyup',function(){...});
```

and I haven't been able to get any working.

Comment: None of those options overwrites previously bound handlers. Can you produce a demo showing your problem?

Comment: What's `$input`?  jQuery event handlers do not "override" other handlers unless the explicitly cancel all event propagation.

Answer (score 3):

You can [Namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) your listeners with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$input.on('keyup.one', function () {})
$input.on('keyup.two', function () {})
```

This will allow you to call `$input.off('keyup.two')` without removing your first listener.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about namespacing events! That is interesting info!

Comment: ^Same.  Problem is, one of the events is from a method I wrote that should be able to be used on any page.  If another developer is using my function, I don't want them to have to remember to namespace their other keyup events.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JarrydGoodman I think you will need to provide more context on what the exact issue is, as mathletics noted, you should be able to add two handlers to an event without issue. Namespacing is just sugar that easily allows you to add and remove _your_ events.

Comment: Jarryd, check your functions and code that are processing the events.   Adding listeners stacks, doesn't overwrite.   This smells more like you have event propagation being stopped by something in your code that executes when one of the events are fired.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an event handler does not clobber previously added event handlers unless [stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) is called.

Here is an example.  When the button is clicked, both event handlers fire.

```js
var $p = $('p');

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $p.append(' *event handler 1* ');
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $p.append(' *event handler 2* ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>click me</button>
<p></p>
```